# How to display directory names in Jenkins drop down

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I wish to display the directory names(not abs. path) of the Jenkins server's */tmp* directory in the Jenkins Drop Down using `Active choice Reactive parameter Plugin`.

I have displayed it by using the below code.
but it was displaying along with its path in the output.

Eg output:

> /tmp/directory1
>   /tmp/directory2

I need the output as :( without the path of the directory)

> directory1
>   directory2

code used in groovy script part of " Active choice Reactive parameter Plugin "

```
import groovy.io.FileType

def list = []

def dir = new File("/tmp/")
dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file ->
  list << file
}

list.each {
  println it.path 
}
```

Comment: Can't you just use `println it.name`

Comment: used `println it.name` getting same output with its path

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go:

Use `DIRECTORIES` instead of `FILES`

```
import static groovy.io.FileType.DIRECTORIES
def list = []
new File('/tmp').eachFileRecurse (DIRECTORIES) { file ->
  list << file.name
}
return list
```

If you do not need recursive, just use `eachFile` instead of `eachFileRecurse`.

**EDIT:** Based on OP's comments,
Use `return list` instead of `print list` as last statement in the above script as to show list in the jenkins.

Comment: used the both, no output was displayed.
under the `/tmp/` folder 3 directories was there .need to display them with out its path. (i.e) not as `/tmp/directory1` just `directory1` in the output

Comment: A tested code snippet is provided to you. It does show. How are you testing?

Comment: Used the above code in the groovy script part of the Jenkins- Active choice reactive parameter plugin without any changes

Comment: Can you try it locally to make sure it is working before using it in jenkins?

Comment: Don't know about jenkins plugin, but you may want to use `return list` instead of print?

Comment: `return list ` instead of `println list` worked.
displayed only the directory name without its path

Comment: [Appreciate if you accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137881/discussion-between-soundararajan-c-and-rao).

Comment: Can I get full jenkins pipeline script please?